Accessible way to disable listbox
I’m developing a package to create sortable lists for web interfaces using Svelte. I’ve already introduced a feature to disable list items individually, allowing the user to focus the disabled items and announcing they are disabled, but not allowing them to be moved.
So now I’m working on a new feature to disable the list as a whole, but I’m not really sure which would be the right approach when putting the focus on accessibility. Should I prevent the user from navigating through the list items when the list is disabled? Should I allow navigation while disabling each list item? What kind of message should I provide to screen readers?

I don't understand the notion of "inactive item in a sortable list". A sortable list is an input control which allows to change the ranking of a set of items. If I have a two-item list with one of them "disabled" (i.e., cannot be moved), I can still move the other item to first or last position, thus effectively creating all the orders which are theoretically possible. What am I missing? What's the use case for "inactive items in sortable list"?

One challenging problem with usability is how all the alt tags are used or omitted by devs. One recommendation is to build the list structure and add the alt labels to each level. For example:
<div alt="List container">
  <ol alt="List of items - locked">
    <li alt="Text - disabled">8</li>
  </ol>
</div>

So, in the  element, you're saying that it is an ordered list, and the whole content is locked, and for each element, the text reader is "reading" the content and its status.

Essentially you need to get your notion of a "user" straight. You are dealing with two levels of them: The developer-user that will incorporate your list on some app and the "real" user (end-user) of that app - who might be using a screen reader.
So it is a good approach to keep the end-user in mind, but the real user you need to support is the developer-user level.
One aspect to consider is the notion of "disabling" vs. "locking". If a single item is disabled it implies to be not usable for interaction at all - but on a dev-user-level one might only want to disable "moving" but still allow navigation (focusing, accessible for a screen reader).
The second notion is disabling the whole control. Here you need to keep in mind that your control will not be the only thing to determine the final state presented to the (end-)user. Your "disabled" property here is a developer-level "disabled" (with a function of "totally" disabled).
Meaning: If a user (=developer) is using your control and wants it to be disabled (= not usable), shi will add another control to enable or disable this list. E.g. a checkbox or radio button which then toggles the "disabled"-property of the list. This button then has to handle how to present itself to a  screen reader. That is: it could state something like "Sorting of items (disabled)". In this case it would be counter-intuitive to still be able to navigate the sortable list. It should be skipped entirely. IF the user(=developer) of your control wants to present it differently shi can leave your list as "enabled" but set it to "locked" (prevent sorting/moving of any items).
Same goes for individually disabled items: If the user(=developer) wants to allow navigating through the list but not allowing moving shi needs a "locked" property on the item button. If the use should be to entirely skip that item shi would need a "disabled" property on the item button in the list.
IF you want to support screen readers on a deep level, you probably need to provide a custom property that allows setting the format that is used to present items to the screen reader, like "%name %state" for example. This property would be adjusted by the dev-user to fit the needs of the app.

I’m sorry, but I don’t feel like your comment really counts as an answer. What you described for the dev users just goes without saying, that’s simply the regular workflow. We add different tools (usually component properties) for them to have proper control over the available features. And then for the end users, it feels to me that you only illustrated the different available possibilities without providing a clear path, which I thought I had already mentioned in my question. Thanks though! :)

Does your list control offer the properties "locked" and "disabled"? What I wanted to make clear is: You cannot provide the necessary UX for an end-user, only the dev-user. The dev-user then needs to deal with the UX for the end-user. In what direction did you think an answer should go?

I disagree. It is my responsibility to provide the tools for the dev user to have control over the different features my package offers, and then it is in his hands to provide custom controls if he wishes to allow the end user to dynamically control the list. But just as well, it is also my responsibility to provide a suitable experience for the end user. Dev users do not have access or control over the internals of my package, they could not control how a list responds to, let’s say, a screen reader. It is my hands to provide a suitable experience for the end users.

And my list currently offers a property to “lock” individual items, to “disable list items individually, allowing the user to focus the disabled items and announcing they are disabled, but not allowing them to be moved”, just like I explained in my question. I did this making use of the aria-disabled attribute to allow disabled items to be focused. I don’t think I need both of what you referred to as “locked” and “disabled”. I think it is my responsibility to choose the better path for both the dev and the end user. So I’m looking for the kind of answer that will help me find that path.

I think we are talking about the same thing but use different terms or points of view on it. Of course your control should offer usability features that a screen reader can benefit from. But you do not know how the dev-user will or will not use those features and present them to the end-user. Therefore your focus should be on the dev-user-level meaning: Give opportunities to support a wide range of scenarios - that was my suggestion with my custom property to control by pattern if and what will be used by a screen reader. With this you help the end-user as well.

Finding a best path is not easy or even impossible because of the huge possible use cases arising by using a screen reader and the habits of their users. For that to optimize you would need to conduct usability tests specifically designed to test your list control in real world scenarios to get hard data on usability. You probably won't find an optimal solution either, just best practices. -- Here now we reached the point were I cannot help you any further. Maybe someone else can or more research for studies on that topic etc. can bring you forward.

Thank you for the effort and the time you put on answering back, Antares :) It is indeed a very specific and intricate situation, so I might not find the right guidance to reach the best possible approach, so I’ll probably just move forward with what I think will provide the best outcome (something I can definitely not be sure about). Thank you, honestly! Have a lovely day :)

Well, if you have a concrete idea or even alternatives you would like to have evaluated, maybe post this as another question. Evaluating pros/cons of some given solutions/suggestions is much easier than giving "the best option for everybody". Best of luck with your project! :)
